# Rails 4, subdomain routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-services, api, subdomain

Trying to implement web service in rails through API sub-domain called "api".
In my `hosts` file i added line: `127.0.0.1       api.localhost`

In my `routes.rb` i set sub-domain, where i only need index action and few manually added restful routes, through following:

```
namespace :api, path: '', :constraints => {:subdomain => "api"} do
  resources :posts, only: :index do
    collection do
      get 'popular_by_day'
      get 'popular_by_week'
    end
  end
end
```

Also generated coresponding controller with: `rails g controller api/posts`

**Test example:**

```
class Api::PostsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @posts = 1

    respond_to do |format|
        format.json  { render :json => @posts }
    end
  end

  def popular_by_day
  end

  def popular_by_week
  end
end
```

After `rake routes` i have following:

```
popular_by_day_api_posts GET  /posts/popular_by_day(.:format)  api/posts#popular_by_day {:subdomain=>"api"}
popular_by_week_api_posts GET  /posts/popular_by_week(.:format) api/posts#popular_by_week {:subdomain=>"api"}
                api_posts GET  /posts(.:format)                 api/posts#index {:subdomain=>"api"}
```

So far as i know, link to http://api.localhost:3000/posts should work but i get routing error: 
**No route matches [GET] "/posts"** (Same with /posts.json)

Comment: Can you try change 127.0.0.1 api.localhost line to 127.0.0.1 api.localhost.local ?

Answer (score 11):

So I'm posting my research on the topic

By default, Rails has its TLD Length set to 1. As a result, it won't be able to determine the subdomain in `api.localhost`, hence, the routing error.

You have several solutions:
- set up a correct domain that points to 127.0.0.1 with a tld length of 1 (e.g. dev-mywebsite.com)
- use lvh.me
- set `config.action_dispatch.tld_length = 0` in your development.rb enrironment file

Hope this helps other people in the same need

Edit:
It is actually not a good idea to use `localhost` so setup an api as a domain in development. I found out that it doesn't work with cookies across subdomains

Answer (score 9):

Try `http://api.lvh.me:3000`for Rails 3+

From [Ryan Bates's railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/221-subdomains-in-rails-3):

> If we go to http://lvh.me:3000/ we’ll see the homepage of our
>   application because lvh.me resolves to the IP address 127.0.0.1. The
>   difference is that we can now prepend any subdomain we like to the URL
>   and it will still point to the same application.

EDIT: I would love to know in the comments why whoever downvoted this answer did so. This approach continues to work for me.

EDIT II: updated the link to Rails Casts from ASCII casts and added note about Rails 3+

Comment: The link is broken. asciicasts.com is a holding page. Try http://railscasts.com/episodes/221-subdomains-in-rails-3?view=asciicast

Comment: It should also be noted that this is for Rails 3

Answer (score 2):

@Srle It seems, I faced this yesterday.

Just try to add ".com" to your subdomain: `api.localhost.com`.

In my app it worked as well: `api.myapplication-dev.com.`

The main reason is that there isn't a .localhost domain, so put .com to your host :)

Hope it works for you as worked for me

Comment: Another way that we can do is: `api.local.host` :)

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this with below steps:

1 – Login as an admin user on terminal:
`sudo su –`

2 – Edit /etc/hosts file
`nano /etc/hosts`

The above command will open **/etc/hosts** file for you in a terminal. You will find a few lines there, the important one is:

`127.0.0.1 localhost`

This is the line which basically maps localhost to IP 127.0.0.1, Add a new line below it:

`127.0.0.1 admin.localhost`

This is telling that the new DNS **admin.localhost** should also map to IP 127.0.0.1, press **CTRL + x** to exist editing
It will ask you to save before existing. Press **Y to save** the change.

3 -restart your rails server.
Now you can access your localhost at both the below URL
`http://localhost:3000/` and `http://admin.localhost:3000`