# Rails Routing: Constraints and Namespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am workin on an api using Rails 6.0.3.4.  The api base_uri will be a subdomain `www.api.example.com` and I also intend to version using Headers.

Currently my routes looks like this:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  namespace :api do
    constraints subdomain: 'api' do
      resources :books, only: [:index]
    end
  end
end
```

My controllers are namespace to make the routes:

```
.
├── api
│   └── books_controller.rb
├── application_controller.rb
└── concerns
```

Code inside `book_controllers`:

```
module Api
  class BooksController < ApplicationController
    def index
      books = Book.all
      render json: books
    end
  end
end
```

With the above route and directory layout,  I expect the url `http://api.localhost:3000/api/books` to return a list of books. Instead I get the error `No route matches [GET] "/api/books"`. I find this confusing because the docs for [request-based-constraints](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#request-based-constraints) uses almost verbatim the same code.

What am I missing please?

Comment: Have you tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26087400/2622934)?  After you change `config/environments/development.rb` you'll have to restart your Rails server.

Comment: @cschroed: thanks for pointing to that link. It did resolve the issue; still need to read a bit on how to handle this in production.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @cschroed's comment I was able to fix this by setting `config.action_dispatch.tld_length = 0` in `config/environments/development`.

The default is 1, which works in prod environments.